# Caching problem with my Visual Web Part when adding it to my List's Create Form

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, visual-studio

I have the following web part inside my visual studio :-

```
 [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling using
        // the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public VisualWebPart1()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroup group = web.Groups["Risk Issue Managers"];
        bool isUser = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.ID);
        if (!isUser)
        {

            SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
            SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
            titleField.Hidden = true;
            titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField.Update();
            SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
            titleField2.Hidden = true;
            titleField2.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField2.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField2.Update();
            SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
            titleField3.Hidden = true;
            titleField3.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField3.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField3.Update();
            SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
            titleField4.Hidden = true;
            titleField4.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField4.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField4.Update();
            SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
            titleField5.Hidden = true;
            titleField5.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField5.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField5.Update();
            SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
            titleField6.Hidden = true;
            titleField6.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField6.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField6.Update();
            myList.Update();
            // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        }
        else
        {
            SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
            SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
            titleField.Hidden = false;
            titleField.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField.Update();
            SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
            titleField2.Hidden = false;
            titleField2.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField2.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField2.Update();
            SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
            titleField3.Hidden = false;
            titleField3.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField3.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField3.Update();
            SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
            titleField4.Hidden = false;
            titleField4.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField4.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField4.Update();
            SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
            titleField5.Hidden = false;
            titleField5.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField5.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField5.Update();
            SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
            titleField6.Hidden =false;
            titleField6.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField6.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField6.Update();
            myList.Update();
            //    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
});

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPGroup group = web.Groups["Risk Issue Managers"];
                    bool isUser = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.ID);
                    if (!isUser)
                    {

                        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
                        SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
                        titleField.Hidden = true;
                        titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField.Update();
                        SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
                        titleField2.Hidden = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField2.Update();
                        SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
                        titleField3.Hidden = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField3.Update();
                        SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
                        titleField4.Hidden = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField4.Update();
                        SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
                        titleField5.Hidden = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField5.Update();
                        SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
                        titleField6.Hidden = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField6.Update();
                        myList.Update();
                        // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
                        SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
                        titleField.Hidden = false;
                        titleField.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField.Update();
                        SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
                        titleField2.Hidden = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField2.Update();
                        SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
                        titleField3.Hidden = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField3.Update();
                        SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
                        titleField4.Hidden = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField4.Update();
                        SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
                        titleField5.Hidden = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField5.Update();
                        SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
                        titleField6.Hidden = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField6.Update();
                        myList.Update();
                        //    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this web part is as follow:-
- if the user is inside the "Risk Issue Group", to see sthe above fields
- if the user is not part of the "Risk Issue Manager" to not be able to see above fields.while he still can see the other fields such as title, modified, etc...

Then i deployed the Web Part and i added it to my default Create form as follow (by adding the web part):-

[image]

Now i am facing this problem:-

- if a user inside the "Risk Issue Manager" group click on create , he will see all the fields, which will be fine.
- but if i remove him from the "Risk Issue Manager" group, then he can still see the fields !!, although inside the web part i mentioned to hide these fields ...

so can anyone advice what is causing this and how to solve it ? could this be related to caching problem? baring in mind that i am displaying the Create form inside a dialog box ? and when the web part is going to run ? each time the user click on Create button?

**EDIT**

This is the new Create form i am trying to edit to remove unwanted fields :-
[image]

Comment: why i have been down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but there is a **lot** of code here that can be refactored into a method.

Comment: ya i got your point , but i want to make my code runs first then i can tune it , any way the code insdie the Page_load() and OnInit() methods are identical .. so can you advice what is cauing the problem in mycase?

Comment: I down voted because this is a terrible implementation, you are updating the list fields constantly on every page load of every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are going about the whole process of hiding fields based on group is completely mislead. Hiding a field will hide the field for the entire list and for everyone. What you are working with is only a view. You can create a new view that will filter out fields based on group membership, but you will be using CSOM and javascript rather than c# code and webparts.

Basically you need to create a custom New Form, Edit Form, and Display Form, make them default. Then you add javascript code that uses CSOM to dive into group membership through the User Profile Service. Then you use simple jquery or javascript to hide the fields that you don't want the user to see in the form. This act of hiding fields will be completely cosmetic.

Comment: ya i got your point actually i find similar question on the web which have this implementation. so now i need to make it simple , can i manually remove unwanted fields from the Create form ? i tried opening the form inside the SharePoint designer but i can not find how to remove certain fields from the Create form ?

Comment: You should be able to hide fields (they will be encased in `<tr>` tags using comments `<!-->` in the markup for the New/Edit/Display forms that you want to edit. Make sure you add new forms and not modify the existing OOB forms. Reason being backup/assurance purposes

Comment: you mean to create a new "Create" form using SharePoint designer ? and how i will be accessing the markup for these forms. as the current forms have .aspx format and not HTML format ?

Comment: You can access them through SharePoint Designer. it will be in markup format. HTML is the format. ASP (or ASPX) stands for Active Server Pages, and it's a technology to get markup code to translate into HTML to the client. Some markup is specific to ASP or API that can be used as object in markup. An example is `SharePoint:FormField` will pass through the servers and translate into HTML markup to the client in the browser. So, in essence there is no ASPX code, just HTML, javascript, and these special markup tags.

Comment: but i read the whole ASPX for the new form ,, but i could not located the form fields,for example i have a field named "comment" and i want to remove it from the create form, but i can not locate it inside the aspx file (the new create form)? can you advice please?

Comment: Ctrl+F to find inside the markup. If you do not find much markup, select the tag ListViewWebPart and make sure the "Server Render" option is checked in the ribbon, then save.

Comment: can you adivice what do u mean by Ctrl+F to find the markup ? what i should search for,, if i type the word "Title" which is the field name , i will not find any text that matches the word Title ??

Comment: i am not sure if we are talking about the same thing. now inside SharePoint designer, i click on a list, then i click on the Create form, i search for the following "ListViewWebPart" but can not find this tag ?? can u advice please?

Comment: can you please check my edit to the original question ,, to see which file i am talking about?

Comment: If you need more help, let's move this to chat [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17550/discussion-between-mike-and-john-g).